# Pasting the values with the format in with, as the date format changes every time

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the values of a date from the sheet "Create new Customer" to "Customer data" and every time the date format changes

```
strName = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(14, 4).Value
strAddress = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(15, 4).Value
strTown = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(16, 4).Value
strPostcode = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(17, 4).Value
strTel = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(18, 4).Value
strEmail = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(19, 4).Value
strEqMk = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(20, 4).Value
strEqMdl = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(21, 4).Value
strEqType = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(22, 4).Value
strEqCost = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(23, 4).Value
strRentalStartDate = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(24, 4).Value
strCond = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(25, 4).Value
strPayT = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(26, 4).Value
strMonthRentalCost = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(27, 4).Value
strPaymentMehtod = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Cells(28, 4).Value


With Sheets("CustomersData")
    .Cells(LastRow, 2).Value = strName
    .Cells(LastRow, 3).Value = strAddress
    .Cells(LastRow, 4).Value = strTown
    .Cells(LastRow, 5).Value = strPostcode
    .Cells(LastRow, 6).Value = strTel
    .Cells(LastRow, 7).Value = strEmail
    .Cells(LastRow, 8).Value = strEqMk
    .Cells(LastRow, 9).Value = strEqMdl
    .Cells(LastRow, 10).Value = strEqType
    .Cells(LastRow, 11).Value = strEqCost
    .Cells(LastRow, 12).Value = strRentalStartDate
    .Cells(LastRow, 13).Value = strCond
    .Cells(LastRow, 14).Value = strPayT
    .Cells(LastRow, 15).Value = strMonthRentalCost
    .Cells(LastRow, 16).Value = strPaymentMehtod

End With
```

Comment: Please tell us more... I only see one date column, are there more ? strRentalStartDate  Please share with us a few of the date formats that you are seeing.  Also, what format of date would you wish to be output  for each of the input date formats?

Comment: Thanks for checking this, in the "Create_New_Customer" I enter the date and it appears in MM,DD,YYY format, and when I submit to create the record in "CustomerData" sheet it appears in the US format and changes to "MM,DD,YYY"  I want it to be there with the same format as it is in the "Create_New_Customer"

and yes its only the strRentalStartDate

Comment: You can copy the Numberformat before you copy the value

Comment: The two date formats appear to be the same "MM,DD,YYY" .  Or is there a typo?

Comment: No there is no typo, I enter the date in the Create new customer sheet and it appears in dd,mm,yyyy when the "with" work to get the values the format changes in the CustomerData sheet to mm,dd,yyyy

Comment: OK, like Tim Williams sez,  add strRentalFormat = Sheets("Create_New_Customer").Range(24, 4).Numberformat  and than after it is moved add .Range(LastRow, 12).Numberformat = strRentalFormat

Comment: Thanks donPablo for this, but its still doing the same, the date format still changes itself to be mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: OK, so lets just force it to be what we want, by adding after moving it, .Range(LastRow, 12).Numberformat = "dd,mm,yyyy"

Comment: Thank you soooo much donPablo it's working perfectly now :-)

Comment: Sorry donPablo, but its still geting the values as if its mm/dd/yyyy   and still not gettiing the format

Comment: It requires me to double click the cell with the date to reflect the new format :(